# Горизонтальный список а-ля ListView?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! Возникла необходимость заполнить горизонтальный список некоторыми маленькими вьюшками (значок и подпись). При том длинна списка заранее не известна (может быть и больше экрана). Как это лучше всего организовать? До этого я делал только ListView и GridView, используя свои адаптеры, наследованные от BaseAdapter.

Comment: Решил испльзовать другую библиотеку (не из ответа), т.к. гораздо проще установить. Вот эту - https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

Все так же, как с со стандартным ListView.

Comment: @vanyamelikov, спасибо большое. А как правильно добавить сею библиотеку? Я пользуюсь Android Studio 0.8.6b.

Comment: Просто создаете новый проект из исходных кодов, в качестве которых указываете разархивированную папку библиотеки. Далее в свойствах вашего проекта во вкладке Android пикаете в разделе библиотека ее. И все она у Вас.

Comment: @vanyamelikov, боюсь, у меня уже есть почти готовый проект. Можно ли просто скопировать папки и добавить пару строк в манифест (не трогая файлы .classpath, .project, proguard-project.txt и project.properties, или же как с ними правильно сработать?)